# Join an ActiveRecord model to a table in another schema with no model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, schema

I need to join an ActiveRecord model in my Ruby on Rails app to another table in a different schema that has no model. I've searched for the answer, and found parts of it, but not a whole solution in one place, hence this question.

I have Vehicle model, with many millions of rows.

I have a table (reload_cars) in another schema (temp_cars) in the same database, with a few million records. This is an ad hoc table, to be used for one ad hoc data update, and will never be used again. There is no model associated with that table.

I initially was lazy and selected all the reload_cars records into an array (reload_vins) in one query, and then in a second query did something like:

```
`Vehicle.where(vin_status: :invalid).where('vin in (?)', reload_vins)`.
```

That's simplified a bit from the actual query, but demonstrates the join I need. In other queries, I need full sets of inner and outer joins between these tables. I also need to put various selection criteria on the model table and/or the non-model table in various steps.

That blunt approach worked fine in development, but did not scale up to the production database. I thought it would take a few minutes, which is plenty fast enough for a one-time operation. But, it timed out, particularly when looping through sets of records. Small tweaks did not help.

So, I need to do a legit join.

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect, the answer seems pretty obvious. This query ran pretty much instantly, and gave the exact expected result, with various criteria on each table.

Here is one such query:

```
Vehicle.where(vin_status: :invalid)
       .joins("
               join temp_cars.reload_cars tcar
               on tcar.vin = vehicles.vin
               where tcar.registration_id is not null
       ")
```